# How is “questions per day on average” computed?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, asking-questions, site-evaluation, publicity

My question, *How is “questions per day on average” computed?*,
is prompted by noticing that Writers SE is still in Beta apparently because the number of questions per day, on average, is below some threshold (5?).  Here is a recent snapshot from the [Writers Area51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1623/writers).  **How many questions need to be asked, over what time period, to qualify the site?**

[image: area51 writers page]

A secondary question: With over 4000 visits per day to the site, why is the questions per day as low as it is?

Note, I found the content of several previous questions ([1](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/493/what-will-become-of-this-site)[2](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/how-is-writers-se-doing-on-good-subjective?rq=1)[3](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/816/how-can-we-reach-out-to-other-se-sites-to-bring-users-here?rq=1)[4](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/how-should-we-promote-the-site?rq=1)[5](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/406/writers-se-from-a-to-z-how-to-spend-time-on-writers-se?rq=1)[6](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/513/publicity-we-need-your-help?rq=1), now linked) to be relevant to my main question in various ways, although not adequate to answer it.